# User can not login problems

Tags: login, solspace-user

Im using Solspace User addon with Username Is Email settings.
However, one of my users seems to have continue problems with their logins.

First time I did just update their profile and setup timezone that was for some reason not set at all, and user did manage to login after that.

Now I got email again, that user didnt manage to login. I did try this and got also the same error: you are not authorized to...

Here is the login form Im using:

```
<div class="col-sm-7 col-md-8">
                  {if logged_out}
                    {exp:member:login_form return="{site_url}" form_class="form-horizontal"}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username" class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="your email" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Your password" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                                <div class="checkbox">

                                    {if auto_login}
                                        <p><input type="checkbox" name="auto_login" value="1"> Remember me?</p>
                                    {/if}

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {/exp:member:login_form}
                    <p><a href="{path="site/forgot-passw"}" class="more-link">Forgot password?</a> <br><a href="{path="site/new-account"}" title="New account" class="more-link">Create free account?</a></p>
                    {/if}
                    {if logged_in}<h3>Ups, you are already logged in!</h3>{/if}
                    </div>
```

Do I miss something or what's might be going on?
I havent been able to reproduce this error with any other account that I have created nor anyone else has emailed me that they cant login.

Comment: Is this user in the correct user group to have permissions for what they are logging in to see?

Comment: Yep. I dont have anything special setups on my site index but a eeXam-based poll thing, it either has nothing special. I just cant figure out what's going on, because havent got login issue emails from others.

Comment: What version of User and EE are you using? Please provide exact version numbers of each. Also, what is the full error message? Is there more than just "_you are not authorized to..._"? What's the URL when you see this message?

Comment: User 3.5.2 and EE 2.9.2 with php 5.6.2. Error message was "The following errors were
encountered. You are not authorized to perform this action
" . I can't pull the error URL for you at the moment cos changed the pw for user and since then havent (yet) heard if user still has issues.